# Implementing Authorization in Polyglot Architecture

Tags: java, .net, security, session, authorization

What is the general practise for handling Authentication in a polyglot architecture (e.g. Java and .Net Server)

Can a session be shared amongst the 2 services written in different technology?

Comment: How do you define "general practise", and why do you assume there is one?

Comment: "*Can a session be shared amongst the 2 services written in different technology?*" Yes because a session is not a language construct, at least in any language I know about.